How to Handle Segment Not Found Errors and Implement Retry Logic in React Native Video Player for HLS Streaming?
I am working on creating a video using HLS (HTTP Live Streaming) with segments generated by AI, where segments are being generated one by one, taking up to several seconds. This video is streamed to an m3u8 URI, and everything is happening simultaneously.
I am playing this m3u8 URI on a React Native app using react-native-video. The issue I am encountering is that the video is playing segment by segment. If any segment is not created yet when the player tries to access it, the video throws a segment_not_found error and stops streaming.
What I want to achieve is to have the video player retry fetching the missing segment instead of stopping the playback. During this retry process, the player should show a buffering indicator.
This is the ERROR:
Video Player Error: {"error": {"errorCode": "22004", "errorException": "androidx.media3.exoplayer.ExoPlaybackException: Source error", "errorStackTrace": "androidx.media3.exoplayer.ExoPlaybackException: Source error

`at androidx.media3.exoplayer.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleIoException(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:684)`
`at androidx.media3.exoplayer.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleMessage(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:656`
`at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)`
`at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:268)`
`at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)`

Caused by: androidx.media3.datasource.HttpDataSource$InvalidResponseCodeException: Response code: 404
`at androidx.media3.datasource.okhttp.OkHttpDataSource.open(OkHttpDataSource.java:353)`
`at androidx.media3.datasource.DefaultDataSource.open(DefaultDataSource.java:272)`
`at androidx.media3.datasource.StatsDataSource.open(StatsDataSource.java:86)`
`at androidx.media3.exoplayer.hls.HlsMediaChunk.prepareExtraction(HlsMediaChunk.java:527)`
`at androidx.media3.exoplayer.hls.HlsMediaChunk.feedDataToExtractor(HlsMediaChunk.java:500)`
`at androidx.media3.exoplayer.hls.HlsMediaChunk.loadMedia(HlsMediaChunk.java:469)`
`at androidx.media3.exoplayer.hls.HlsMediaChunk.load(HlsMediaChunk.java:426)`
`at androidx.media3.exoplayer.upstream.Loader$LoadTask.run(Loader.java:414)`
`at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)`
`at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)`
`at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)`
", "errorString": "ExoPlaybackException: ERROR_CODE_IO_BAD_HTTP_STATUS"}}

I've tried fetching segments one by one and and applying exponential backoff on segment refetch, but it causes delays and gaps in video playback and this approach really didn't worked out Segment generation and video playback are happening simultaneously, so I am relying entirely on react-native-video. However, it breaks the stream when an error occurs and does not attempt to reload or play the video unless I navigate away and return or reload the app.
